C++ function template implementation to find the min/max value from three vectors
I am given the below "interface" to implement:
enum class minmax_t : uint8_t { MIN, MAX };
template <minmax_t M, typename T>
constexpr T get(const std::vector<T> &v1, const std::vector<T> &v2, const std::vector<T> &v3);

so that the following driver function should return the min/max value from three vectors:
auto max = get<minmax_t::MIN, double>(v0, v1, v2);
auto min = get<minmax_t::MAX, int>(v0, v1, v2);

where v0, v1 and v2 are std::vectors of elements that can be compared. My implementation is below:
template <minmax_t M, typename T>
constexpr T get(const std::vector<T> &v1, const std::vector<T> &v2,
                const std::vector<T> &v3) {

  if constexpr (M == minmax_t::MAX) {
    auto v1m = *std::max_element(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    auto v2m = *std::max_element(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    auto v3m = *std::max_element(v3.begin(), v3.end());
    if (v1m > v2m && v1m > v3m)
      return v1m;
    if (v2m > v1m && v2m > v3m)
      return v2m;
    return v3m;
  } else {
    auto v1m = *std::min_element(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    auto v2m = *std::min_element(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    auto v3m = *std::min_element(v3.begin(), v3.end());
    if (v1m < v2m && v1m < v3m)
      return v1m;
    if (v2m < v1m && v2m < v3m)
      return v2m;
    return v3m;
  }
}

It worked, but given the vastness of metaprogramming and STL, it is very likely that I missed some gems from C++ to make the implementation better (e.g., more expressive/concise/performant). Any thoughts?

The specification is valid if the total number of elements across all three vectors is at least one, but your implementation only works if all three vectors are individually non-empty.  So I'd argue that it is too early to discuss expressive/concise/performant, because it is not correct.

@BenVoigt pls let us have your correct version, with correct in italics

Toby's version using concat/join is correct (in regard to the bug mentioned above), because it doesn't require min or max to exist for individual vectors.

yes but you made the comment after his post, so I suppose you must have something very interesting/insightful to supplement. It is so great that it must be in italics so I am eagerly waiting for it.

The interface (using an enum to select between two implementations) is a bit unconventional, given that the standard library has std:minmax() and that this family of standard algorithms all accept a comparator function.  And the dependence on std::uint8_t existing.  But neither of those are your fault.
We're missing a couple of headers whose declarations we use: <algorithm> and <vector>.
Instead of duplicating the code for min and max, perhaps we should use common code, but choose between std::less<T> and std::greater<T> according to the value of M?
When we have the min/max value from each vector, we should apply std::ranges::max/std::ranges::min to that set of values, rather than hand-crafting the greatest-of three.
Talking of ranges, the views library allows us create a concatenation of all three arrays and treat them as a single range:
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

enum class minmax_t : std::uint8_t { MIN, MAX };

template <minmax_t M, typename T>
constexpr T get(const std::vector<T> &v1,
                const std::vector<T> &v2,
                const std::vector<T> &v3)
{
#if __cpp_lib_ranges_concat >= 202403L // from C++26
    auto view = std::views::concat(v1, v2, v3);
#else  // C++ 20
#else  // C++ 20
    auto arr = std::array{
        std::views::all(v1),
        std::views::all(v2),
        std::views::all(v3)
    };
    auto view = std::views::join(arr);
#endif

    if constexpr (M == minmax_t::MAX) {
        return std::ranges::max(view);
    } else {
        return std::ranges::min(view);
    }
}

One advantage here is that it works when some of the vectors are empty, as long as there's at least one element in total.  It exhibits UB only if all three vectors are empty, compared with the original which is undefined if any one of the vectors is empty.
Using ranges allows us to make the interface more general in a compatible manner by accepting any number of any kind of input range, rather than a fixed number of std::vector:
template <minmax_t M, std::ranges::input_range... R>
constexpr auto get(R&&... ranges)
{
#if __cpp_lib_ranges_concat >= 202403L // from C++26
    auto view = std::views::concat(std::forward<R>(ranges)...);
#else  // C++ 20
    auto arr = std::array{ std::views::all(std::forward<R>(ranges))... , };
    auto view = std::views::join(arr);
#endif
    ⋮


Here's the simple test program I used to exercise the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
int main()
{
    using svv = std::vector<std::string_view>;
    svv a{ "foo", "bar", "baz", "quux" };
    svv b{ "green", "yellow", "blue" };
    svv c{ "rough", "hairy", "smooth", "wet" };

    std::cout << get<minmax_t::MIN>(a, b, c) << '\n';
    std::cout << get<minmax_t::MAX>(a, b, c) << '\n';
}

I think it would be better if we created a small set of unit tests to thoroughly exercise the code (what if all inputs are empty, for instance?  Should we be returning std::optional<T> instead?).

In any case, auto x = {...}; is a really, really terrible idea, not least because it will behave differently depending on which version of C++ your compiler is using. It’s not only safer to explicitly make it an array with auto x = std::array{...}; (or a tuple, depending), it can actually be more efficient. I would say, generally, avoid std::initializer_list.

@indi, I'd be interested in your reasoning about efficiency, though that probably doesn't fit in a comment.  I've always struggled with array type deduction: std::array{a, b, c} gives a warning about missing braces around the initializer, but std::array{{a, b, c}} fails altogether with no matching function for call to array(<brace-enclosed initializer list>).  What's the recommended solution?

Odd, I don’t get a warning with pedantic, all, and extra on either GCC or Clang. (The issue with doubling the braces makes sense, because now you’re not using an initializer list, you’re using an initializer_list, and array does not have a constructor for that.) As for the efficiency issue, at least one part is easy to explain: initializer_list is a list of const objects, so you can’t move your final return value from it. There is also a potential issue of memory locality because initializer_list might put your stuff in static memory.

@indi, looking at my CXXARGS, it seems I've asked for -Wmissing-braces but didn't realise the consequences here.  It may not be a warning that I actually want, after all.  At least until issue 95330 is addressed.

Also discussed in Is it wise to ignore gcc/clang's "-Wmissing-braces" warning?.

So long story short, it is pretty sure that auto arr = std::array{ std::views::all(v1), std::views::all(v2), std::views::all(v3)}; would not lead to extra/unnecessary copy?

@D.J.Elkind That's right - the array of views doesn't copy any of the elements.

@TobySpeight is it because std:array initializes its members by calling elements' constructor, and a view's constructor does not copy the underlying data?

@D.J.Elkind, yes.
